# Quickly replacing information of a pandas dataframe using other dataframe and series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, pandas-loc

I am currently trying to replace information of a DataFrame using another DataFrame and a series for my simulation analysis.

Toy example is as follows

A is a user info DataFrame, B is a service info DataFrame, and C is series information about whether the user changed service.

```
TableA (user's current service info):
        cost   location
John    100    Tokyo
Tom     50     Seoul
Andy    50     Seoul
Mark    80     Seoul

TableB (service info):
             cost    location
premium_T    100     Tokyo
basic_T      60      Tokyo
premium_S    80      Seoul
basic_S      50      Seoul

Table C (service change info):
        change        
John    no  
Tom     no     
Andy    premium_S      
Mark    basic_S
```

using above data, I'd like to change information in Table A, using data in Table B and C. In other words, I desire:

```
TableA' (modified user's service info):
        cost   location
John    100    Tokyo
Tom     50     Seoul
Andy    80     Seoul
Mark    50     Seoul
```

The code I used is:

```
TableA = pd.DataFrame(index = ['John', 'Tom', 'Andy', 'Mark'], 
                      data = {'cost': [100,50,50,80],
                     'location': ['Tokyo', 'Seoul', 'Seoul', 'Seoul']})

TableB = pd.DataFrame(index = ['premium_T', 'basic_T', 'premium_S', 'basic_S'],
                      data = {'cost': [100, 60, 80, 50],
                     'location': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Seoul','Seoul']})  
    
TableC = pd.Series( ['no', 'no', 'premium_S', 'basic_S'], index = ['John', 'Tom', 'Andy', 'Mark'])
    
customer_list = TableA.index.tolist()

for k in customer_list:
    if TableC.loc[k] != 'no':
        TableA.loc[k] = TableB.loc[TableC.loc[k]]
```

The code works, and provides the results that I desire.

However, I have to do such work for a very big dataset repeatedly, and I need faster method to do such replacements.

Any ideas? I think repeated use of `.loc` is the problem, but I have not found probable solution yet. I have looked at `pd.update()` or `pd.replace()`, but it does not seem to be what I am looking for.

Comment: a minimal example e.g. `Table1 = pd.DataFrame(...)` might help too then people can copy / paste rather than guessing

Comment: I will add modify it thank you

Comment: I guess @AlexanderMcFarlane suggested that maybe it's better to share `Table1.to_dict()`

Comment: I have made modifications.. is this what you mean? sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: is `TableC` actually a series, or can it be a dataframe?

Comment: It is actually a series.. sorry for the confusion... I have modified it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate in-scope customers from `TableC` using `reindex` and Boolean indexing:

```
idx = TableC.reindex(TableA.index & TableC.index)
idx = idx[idx != 'no']
```

Then update `TableA` via `loc`:

```
TableA.loc[np.in1d(TableA.index, idx.index)] = TableB.reindex(idx.values).values
```

Result:

```
       cost location
John  100.0    Tokyo
Tom    50.0    Seoul
Andy   80.0    Seoul
Mark   50.0    Seoul
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! The code remarkably enhanced the performance of my code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If we convert everything to dataframes with named columns, we can use merges to pull in the correct information:

```
TableA = TableA.reset_index().rename({'index': 'person'}, axis='columns')
TableB = TableB.reset_index().rename({'index': 'cost_plan'}, axis='columns')
TableC = TableC.to_frame(name='cost_plan').reset_index().rename({'index': 'person'}, axis='columns')

new_costs = TableA.merge(TableC, how='left').merge(TableB, how='left',
                                                   on=['location', 'cost_plan'],
                                                   suffixes=['_old', '_new'])

new_costs['cost_new'].fillna(new_costs['cost_old'], inplace=True)
```

`new_costs` then looks like:

```
  person  cost_old location  cost_plan  cost_new
0   John       100    Tokyo         no     100.0
1    Tom        50    Seoul         no      50.0
2   Andy        50    Seoul  premium_S      80.0
3   Mark        80    Seoul    basic_S      50.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! By using your method, I think I can create a bigger dataframe, with less time. Thank you!